# Which classes/namespace to use for image-processing in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have prototyped a library with some image-processing algorithms in Python/Numpy/Scipy, and now I want to port the code to C# and WPF.

I have realized that, although the input files are images (photographs), conceptually what matters to my domain problem is that they are bidimensional arrays of floats, and the operations I perform (grayscale conversion, blur, blob detection, skeletonization), and even persistence, are best performed in floating-point "space", rather than in integer space (which means bytes - uint8 -, usually).

So, I took a look at .NET namespaces, and there are a lot of "Drawing" this, "Imaging" that, "Media" something, and I am utterly confused.

So, the question is: Which .NET class is the most obvious and commonly used "image data container" for floating point image processing.

I know about AForge, but since I am learning C# and my image-processing needs are not so heavy at this point, I'd like to give native .NET a chance (but that could be a bad idea anyway, so please let me know if it is).

Comment: Good question. The fastest access that I've seen is by getting a pointer to the bytes of a Bitmap...so perhaps reading/translating those bytes into a floating point space in a new array and then operating on the resulting array.

Comment: Why not use float arrays directly www.codeproject.com/Articles/34041/Convert-the-image-to-float-float-T-T-data-fast-and

Comment: @user629926 I suppose there might be some image classes with "embedded" useful methods related to basic image processing. If I use pure raw arrays, perhaps I would have to implement these methods myself. And it would be also necessary to know which are the preferred classes used by the most widespread image processing in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you already have, why not looking for the same libraries you used in Python but for C#/.NET? for example, for numeric calculations look at:

Project:
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

Examples: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/tree/master/src/Examples

And for examples of image processing, maybe looking at the source code of Paint.NET (its latest open sourced version - openpdn  Fork of Paint.NET 3.36.7) may give you an idea of what libraries to use for images:

http://code.google.com/p/openpdn/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc

Both libraries are in C#.